# How to autowire Spring bean in Wicket Session class?

Tags: java, spring, wicket

I have a Wicket Session class as follows

```
public class IASession extends AuthenticatedWebSession {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3529263965780210677L;

    @SpringBean
    private UserService userService;

    public IASession(Request request) {
        super(request);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {

        // Get the user
        UserDetailsDTO user = userService.findByEmail(username);

        if(null != user && user.getPassword().equals(password))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Roles getRoles() {
        Roles roles = new Roles();
        roles.add("SIGNED_IN");
        return roles;
    }
}
```

In this class, I am trying to autowire Spring service using wicket-spring annnotation `@SpringBean`. But when I am trying to login, it giving me error.

```
Last cause: null
WicketMessage: Method onFormSubmitted of interface org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.IFormSubmitListener targeted at [StatelessForm [Component id = login-form]] on component [StatelessForm [Component id = login-form]] threw an exception
```

Wicket is unable to autowire the `userService` spring bean and that is why it's `null`.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I've not used Wicket before, but is IASession visible within the Spring application context? I don't see any annotation on this class that would indicate it is. If your target class isn't managed by Spring, you can't autowire anything in it. In addition, is your UserService also managed by Spring?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the Session is not a Component or Behavior you'll have to overwrite the constructor and call Injector.get.inject(this). See the [SpringComponentInjector](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/spring/injection/annot/SpringComponentInjector.html) doc.

```
    public IASession(Request request) {
       super(request);
       Injector.get().inject(this);
    }
```

Comment: You seem to have experience with Wicket with Spring. If you know any reference site for Wicket + Spring do let me know.

Thanks, it did solve my problem :)